# Searching collection records by relationship attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a game where people can get some items and equip them.

The items data is placed in two tables that are in relationship.

`Items` table contains all the possible items and `user_items` table contains the items that are owned by a player.

**user_items** table: **id | user_id | item_id | is_equipped**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function userItems()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(UserItem::class);
    }
}
```

**items** table: **id | item_name | body_part**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class UserItem extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Item::class, 'id', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

Now I am getting a collection of the user's items
`$userItems = UserItem::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get(),`

How do I search this collection by related table's columns? For example I want to get user `$userItems` where `is_equipped == 1` and `body_part == "head"`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is filter by the relation like this:

```
$userItems = UserItem::where('user_id', Auth::id())->whereHas('items', function($q)
{
    $q->where('is_equipped', '=', 1);

})->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! Works well but I cannot get item_name now from the related object. Ehh thats complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Eloquent's relationships to search the collection by related table's columns.

To get the user's items where is_equipped == 1 and body_part == "head", you can use the following code:

```
$userItems = UserItem::where('user_id', Auth::id())
->whereHas('items', function ($query) {
    $query->where('is_equipped', 1)->where('body_part', 'head');
})->get();
```

This code first queries the user_items table for all items that belong to the user. Then, it uses the **whereHas** method to filter the results based on the related items table's columns. The closure passed to **whereHas** receives a $query variable that is a instance of Query Builder that you can use to filter the items table.

You could also use the **join** method to join the items table to the user_items table and then filter by the columns in the items table:

```
 $userItems = UserItem::join('items', 'items.id', '=', 'user_items.item_id')
    ->where('user_items.user_id', Auth::id())
    ->where('items.is_equipped', 1)
    ->where('items.body_part', 'head')
    ->get();
```

This will give you a collection of user_items that are owned by the user and have is_equipped = 1 and body_part = 'head' in the items table.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question! Is there any way to get the `items.item_name` using the first case? The returned collection shows me only `user_items` attributes

Comment: No idea why these model relations attributes cannot be used directly somehow. Anyway I think I will stick to the second answer. Works as hell.